# Bloquear se digitar apenas uma palavra em um TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

eu trabalho com C# - WPF e tenho um campo onde o cliente pode digitar seu nome completo.
Gostaria de validar onde ele não pode digitar apenas o primeiro nome se não abre uma mensagem bloqueando. Ou seja, ele precisaria digitar pelo menos dois nomes.

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma, mas ele so pega os espaços que vem antes do primeiro nome

```
bool espaco= txtBox1.Text.Length>0 && txtBox1.Text.Trim().Length==0;

if (espaco){
    MessageBox.Show("Erro");
}
```

Deu pra entender, caso contrario eu tento explicar melhor...
Me ajudem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para contar o número de *palavras* (nomes) na string, usa:

- `String.Trim` para eliminar espaços no início e no fim da string
- `String.Split` para dividir a string numa coleccao de palavras
- `Array.Length` para contar o número de palavras

```
var wordCount = txtBox1.Text
                       .Trim()
                       .Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Length;

if (wordCount < 2){
    MessageBox.Show("Erro: insira o nome completo.");
}
```

A opção `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` é necessária para os casos em que o utilizador insere dois ou mais espaços entre palavras, ex: `Diogo   Castro`.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cIMd7f

Comment: Perfeita explicação amigo, e funcionou perfeitamente... Obrigado xDD